# How should User Agents deal with non-integer values for tabindex and z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index, tabindex

I have some code I'm supporting that has `tabindex="1.1"`, `tabindex="1.2"`, etc. I'm thinking about changing the values to be integers. Would this improve browser behaviour?

[W3C says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#tabbing-navigation):

> **tabindex** = *number* [CN]
>
> This attribute specifies the position of the current element in the tabbing order for the current document. This value must be a number between 0 and 32767. User agents should ignore leading zeros.

It doesn't say how non-integer values should be treated.

[This reference](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/ref-elements.html) says:

> NUMBER
>
> A number. Numbers must begin with a hyphen or digit and can include the decimal point.

So the markup is valid if you use a decimal point but does it make sense?

My question is should user agents honour the decimal point and the digits after it or just use the integer part? i.e. should the two values above be treated as the same or different? Why would you use those values in favour of `tabindex="11"`, `tabindex="12"`, etc.? The same goes for z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in David's answer, the current HTML/CSS specifications clearly require an integral value for these properties.  Decimal values are not meant to be supported.

> should the two values above be treated as the same or different?

In terms of should, I would have thought they would be treated as different values, and basically parsed as floating-point numbers.  However a quick jsFiddle test shows otherwise, in Chrome at least.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="start here" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 3" tabindex="1.3" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 2" tabindex="1.2" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 1" tabindex="1.1" />
<hr />
<input type="text" placeholder="start here" tabindex="10" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 3" tabindex="13" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 2" tabindex="12" />
<input type="text" placeholder="tab 1" tabindex="11" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NWKt4/2/

> Why would you use those values in favour of tabindex="11",
>   tabindex="12", etc.?

Based upon the results above, I'd suggest that you wouldn't/shouldn't use decimal values in favor of integral ones, since they don't appear to work as one might expect.

> My question is should user agents honour the decimal point and the
>   digits after it or just use the integer part?

That seems somewhat subjective.  So my subjective answer is that yes, of course they should.

In practice, however, it does not appear that mainstream browsers (Firefox does the same thing as Chrome, as does IE) honor the fractional component of the `tabindex` value.  And the HTML/CSS spec says that this should be an integral value.

Edit:  and the same applies to `z-index` as well:  http://jsfiddle.net/NWKt4/3/

Comment: By "should" I meant defined in a specification as "should", "must", "may", etc. rather than a personal opinion. My personal opinion would be that it shouldn't, but my opinion doesn't matter if there is a specification that says something else. Thanks for the jsfiddles!

Comment: It isn’t subjective. It is stated in the spec for both `z-index` property and `tabindex` attribute that both accept only numbers that are integers.

Comment: @DavidStorey - Correct.  I was going off the info provided in the OP, which just said that the value should be a number, and that a "number" could include a decimal point/fractional component.

Comment: Where do you expect to find the “official” HTML and CSS specifications if not at W3C?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - Yes, I confused them with W3Schools.  Stupid concept dyslexia on my part.  I'd delete it if the page would let me.  Guess edit will have to do.

Answer (score 7):

A `z-index` with a decimal place will be ignored, as it is invalid:

“Value:  auto | <integer> | inherit” – [CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index).

You can check this yourself by using the [CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FE4Qxb%2Fshow%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en).

You can see that decimal places in the `tabindex` attribute are also invalid by checking the [HTML5 Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2FE4Qxb%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

“Bad value 1.2 for attribute tabindex on element div: Expected a digit but saw . instead”

If you check the spec it states:

“The tabindex attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a valid integer.” – [HTML5.1 Spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute)

Error handling in HTML5 works differently than CSS. In this case as the value has to be an integer, it follows the [rules for parsing an integer](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-integers). The relevant parts are that “When invoked, the steps must be followed in the order given, aborting at the first step that returns a value.” and “If the character indicated by position is not an ASCII digit, then return an error.” The decimal place is not an ASCII digit, so an error will be returned, and the digit before the decimal place will be used as the integer. In this case 1 for each `tab index`.

Comment: Good answer! You'd expect the HTML and CSS specs to agree, wouldn't you?

Comment: The validators do not tell what browsers should do with the errors. Neither do the parts of specs and drafts quoted here.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The CSS spec clearly states that invalid CSS should be ignored. That is how error handling works in CSS. The HTML5 spec also defines error handling. I included links to the validator with an included demo to illustrate that they are invalid.

Comment: CSS has error processing rules, but this answer does not refer to them. This answer does not refer to HTML5 error processing rules, and if taken as an answer to the question in the title, gives the impression that the attributes are ignored, which is not the case.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I state in the first line that z-index will be ignored. I just don't link to the part of the spec that defines error handling.

Answer (score 3):

One possible reason for this is to make up for an original developer not having the foresight to leave gaps in the tabindex scheme.

Original developer goes through and gives form fields tabindexes 1,2,3, so on, up to some large number.

Next developer adds more fields in between fields 1 and 2 but can't insert them into the tabindex scheme correctly without renumbering everything that comes after it, which is kinda lame.

So next developer uses 1.1, 1.2, etc. instead. If it works and it's valid, it's fine. Ideally you'd use integers though.

Comment: You might think that, however, all of the tabindexes start with "1."! Go figure!

Comment: Actually, using decimal values seems to work in Chrome as of this date.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in the title (How should User Agents deal with non-integer values for tabindex and z-index?) is the following:

- HTML 4.01 (which was quoted in the question) does not specify rules for this. It explicitly says (in [4.1 Definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/conform.html#h-4.1)) that it “does not define how conforming user agents handle general error conditions”. However, it recommends that “If a user agent encounters an attribute value it doesn't recognize, it should use the default attribute value.” The `tabindex` attribute has no default value, so it is unclear how this should be interpreted.
- HTML5 CR, which is often cited as if it were a standard, [defines the `tabindex` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex) so that its value is “parsed using the rules for parsing integers”, which is defined so that parsing stops at the period “.” character in the given cases, and both attributes are parsed as `tabindex="1"`.
- The `z-index` property is CSS, not HTML. By [CSS rules for handling parsing errors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors), “user agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value”. For example, `#foo { z-index: 1.2; width: 60% }` shall thus be treated as `#foo { width: 60% }` (i.e., the *declaration* with illegal value is ignored, but other declarations in the same rule are processed normally).

In practice, browsers apply the HTML5 CR principle here (or, rather, HTML5 CR has been written to reflect browser practice). Tested on IE, Firefox, Chrome. However, although IE 11 handles erroneous code `tabindex="1.1"` correctly, it fails to do so for some other error cases (like `tabindex="42A"`, which is incorrectly treated as `tabindex=0`).

Thus, changing the values to integers would be correct (the current code is incorrect by any HTML specification). Whether it will improve browser behavior depends on what the code is meant to do and what values you would use. As it is probable that the values are expected to have different effects (as opposite to being both taken as `tabindex="1"`), you should set them to different integers. If the elements are meant to appear in tabbing order between elements with `tabindex` values 1 and 2, you cannot achieve that—you would need to modify those other values too, with due consideration of all `tabindex` values used on the page.

The other reference in the question is for DocBook Element Reference, which has as such nothing to do with HTML.

Regarding the question “Why would you use those values?”, we can only speculate that an author had `tabindex="1"` and `tabindex="2"` and needed to put something between them in tabbing order, and mistakenly thought that numbers with a decimal point could be used. The mistake may have gone unnoticed, since elements with the same `tabindex` value are, by the specs and in practice, placed in the tabbing order so that their mutual order is by their order in HTML source—and this may match the intentions.